# pythonからtwitterを使って、中国語のツイートを取得したい

Tags: python, twitter

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからツイートを取得したいです。
日本語と英語などできましたが、中国語でできません。
中国では、twitterが禁止されています。その影響もあるかもしれません。
台湾では中国語も使っているので、中国語の表示もできると思います。

もしわかる方いれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxx'


# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        json_load = json.loads(data)
        texts = json_load['text']
        coded = texts.encode('utf-8')
        s = str(coded)
        print(s[2:-1])
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

# This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
stream.filter(track=[u'東京', ], languages=['ja'])
```

## 実行結果

```
�はようございます☀
もふもふ１のイケメンぼっくんしかし最近ランクイン出来ず
今日はいい天気ですので、ご来店お待ちしております。
#フクロウカフェ #ふくろうカフェ #もふもふ #新宿 #東京 #都庁 #Owl… https://t.co/e8T0lwq7s
�速報】NTTドコモがAIでタクシーを配車するって！2017年予定らしい。 - おぼえて書くだけ！ https://t.co/OKjFxzsBos #タクシー #人工知能 #NTT #ドコモ #東京 #オリンピッ��
�並区成田西２丁目
…すい環境です。伊藤忠商事１００％出資子会社のイトーピアホームによる自由設計です。まずは周辺環境を含め現地をご覧…　詳細はＨＰで！　
 https://t.co/yzt9P3mmPY
広告有効期限16/10/11
 #不動産 #東京 #戸建 #新��
```

Comment: フェイクが入っているなら大丈夫ですがアクセストークンとかは隠した方が良いのでは…？

Answer (score 3):

最後の行を次のように書き換えて実行したら動きましたよ。

```
stream.filter(track=[u'中国', ], languages=['zh'])
```

結果

```
9月29日[亚洲自由电台新闻] 泛亚追踪——#云南卫视 当初如何报道 #泛亚？ https://t.co/....
```

## 沖縄発信のツイートだけ取得する方法

地域限定は`locations=[経度、緯度、経度、緯度]`で囲まれる箱を指定します。Google Mapで適当にクリックすると緯度経度(latitude, longitude)が得られます。Tweepyはなぜか(longitude, latitude)の順序で指定することになっていますので、気をつけます。406が出るときは人口が多そうな小さな地域でまず試してください。その後拡大してみましょう。

zh指定だとすぐ結果がわからないのでjaでやって見ました。

```
OKINAWA = [127.672482, 26.088887, 128.275025, 26.851451]
stream.filter(languages=['ja'], locations=OKINAWA)
```

結果

```
ほんと！沖縄に台風はつきもの�
```

Comment: ご丁寧に対応いただき誠にありがとうございます。沖縄県に来る台湾人のツイートを取得したいですが可能ですか。下記のリンクに沖縄県の入域観光客数概況が載っています。http://www.pref.okinawa.jp/site/bunka-sports/kankoseisaku/kikaku/statistics/tourists/documents/h28-8gaikyou.pdf

Comment: 沖縄発信のツイートを取得する方法を追記しました。`locations=[経度、緯度、経度、緯度]`で囲まれる箱を指定します。

Comment: 度々、すいません。　　stream.filter(track=[u'沖縄', ], languages=['zh'], locations =[26.2124,127.6809,30 ])のようにやってみましたが、下記のエラーが表示されます。

Comment: File "cuatro.py", line 34, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=[u'沖縄', ], languages=['zh'], locations =[26.2124,127.6809,30 ])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 434, in filter
    raise TweepError("Wrong number of locations points, "
tweepy.error.TweepError: Wrong number of locations points, it has to be a multiple of 4

Comment: TAIWAN = [121.487859, 25.076104,120.666631,24.152225]
stream.filter(track=[u'沖県', ], languages=['zh'], locations=TAIWAN)　　　　台湾のツイートを取得したいですが、下記のエラーが表示されます。

Comment: root@localhost デスクトップ]# python cuatro.py
406
406
406
^[^[^[^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "cuatro.py", line 35, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=[u'沖県', ], languages=['zh'], locations=TAIWAN)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 255, in _run
    sleep(self.retry_time)
KeyboardInterrupt